# Phantom Contact Account Appearing - Android

Tags: android, contacts, phantom-reference

I am writing an app that allows the user to select from a list of names and then add one of the names (with phone number, etc) to their contacts. When I retrieve my phone's list of Contact Accounts, I am getting 3 results: "Phone", "a000000229aa3e....", "Gmail".

The center result, "a000000229aa3e...." is not an account that I have setup or appears anywhere else on my phone. This also does not appear in the emulator.

My coworker ran it on hit Droid (original Droid) and did not get the odd account. I am running it on a Droid X.

Does anyone know where this Contact Group is coming from? Is there something I need to do to filter this out?

---

I was able to get the name and type for the odd contact account:
Account Name: a00000229aa3e5-8877431712057062230@random.svcmot.com
Account Type: com.motorola.blur.service.bsutils.MOTHER_USER_CREDS_TYPE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I could gather, MOTHER_USER_CREDS_TYPE indicates some sort of Motorola/Provider created account... I ended up filtering this out with `!(mAccounts.get(i).getType().toString().contains("MOTHER_USER_CREDS_TYPE"))` - I don't know if this will hold up across all devices but it fixed my problem, for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know all that much about Android apps, but is your phone made by Motorola? or was your previous phone made by Motorola and you copied settings across?

If so it could be a default account, can you see this account when not using your application?

Comment: It is a Motorola phone, it was not transfered from another phone. I cannot see the account in the phone settings anywhere.